# How can I convert datetime to date, truncating the times, leaving me the dates?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field that's in datetime format when date would be better and more consistent with the rest of the database, so I want to convert. The time part is all 00:00:00 anyway.

How can I do this in MySQL?

Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT CAST(NOW() AS DATE))`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want this in a `SELECT`-Statement, just use the `DATE` Operator:

```
SELECT DATE(`yourfield`) FROM `yourtable`;
```

If you want to change the table structurally, just change the datatype to `DATE` (of course only do this if this doesn't affect applications depending on this field).

```
ALTER TABLE `yourtable` CHANGE `yourfield` `yourfield` DATE;
```

Both will eliminate the time part.

Comment: I currently have some records in the table, so how can i change the database structure.

Comment: This question and my old answer should provide some information on how to do that. If not, please ask a new question in StackOverflow while displaying your current table structure and an excerpt of your data (with format).

Answer (score 5):

Cast it as a DATE:

```
select DATE(my_date_time)
```

That will truncate the time from it, leaving only the date part.

Comment: fast and simple solution

Answer (score 1):

when using change we have to repeat the same name again for the field.now we can use `MODIFY` to alter the filed type.

`` ALTER TABLE `yourtable` MODIFY `yourfield` DATE; ``

Comment: I want to truncate a table records for past 2 months 

`TRUNCATE meter_to_sim_mapping WHERE meter_to_sim_mapping.mapped_at <=`

How can I add time here ?

Comment: you cannot truncate with WHERE clause. With truncate you only clear the whole table. If you need WHERE condition use DELETE