# Get Dates for SQL

Tags: mysql, reporting

I have a table and I want to get the year month and date from. So basically I want this 
'2010-06-08' and do not want this '2010-06-08 11:03:25.797' The table gives me the second option but I only want to get the year month and day. Heres is my codec it is a stored procedure.

```
    ALTER PROC [dbo].[spAdminCancelRefundDate]

    (@Beginning_Date  DATE, 
     @Ending_Date DATE,
     @program int=null)

As
Begin

  SELECT  @program, c.program_id, d.dealer_code,b.last_name As DealerName, a.account_no, a.vin,  ((e.last_name)+','+(e.first_name)) As Name, 
  a.cancel_refund_date, a.purchase_date,a.miles, a.duration,a.sale_price,a.number_of_payments,  a.sales_tax, a.downpayment

from tDealer d 
    Join tContact b ON d.contact_id = b.contact_id 
    Join tContract a On d.dealer_id = a.dealer_id 
    Join tCompany c ON d.company_id= c.company_id
    Join tContact E On e.contact_id = a.contact_id

    Where c.program_id = @program And a.cancel_refund_date between @Beginning_Date and @Ending_Date
End
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert datetime to date, truncating the times, leaving me the dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527315/how-can-i-convert-datetime-to-date-truncating-the-times-leaving-me-the-dates)

Comment: You've tagged this "mysql" but used sql-server syntax.  Which do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

use date function in mysql. You can see official site [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date).

```
mysql> SELECT DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03');
        -> '2003-12-31'
```

Or if you want to format that date consider this,

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%W %M %Y');
        -> 'Sunday October 2009'
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2007-10-04 22:23:00', '%H:%i:%s');
        -> '22:23:00'
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('1900-10-04 22:23:00',
    ->                 '%D %y %a %d %m %b %j');
        -> '4th 00 Thu 04 10 Oct 277'
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('1997-10-04 22:23:00',
    ->                 '%H %k %I %r %T %S %w');
        -> '22 22 10 10:23:00 PM 22:23:00 00 6'
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('1999-01-01', '%X %V');
        -> '1998 52'
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2006-06-00', '%d');
        -> '00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using the call `DATE()` on a `DATETIME` object will return just the date portion of it. For example:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03');
-> '2003-12-31'
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) is the Doc for more MYSQL DateTime functions.