# How to convert datetime to simple date in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

Been trying to convert 
`givenDate -> 2009-06-29 00:00:000` into `requiredDate ->20090629`

Have tried using `Convert function` but non of them seems to do the trick as the version of MySql doesn't recognize Date_Format either.

Believe there should be a simple way to convert this, any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527315/how-can-i-convert-datetime-to-date-truncating-the-times-leaving-me-the-dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this as convering  it into `convert (nvarchar,giventime,112)`